# Checkbox a imagen sumar valores

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un formulario con checkbox que al tildar las opciones se suman los valores en un campo... ahora estoy cambiando los checkbox por imágenes, pero no logro que se sumen al seleccionarlas como antes!

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"][id^="myCheckbox"] {
  display: true;
}
:checked + label {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

:checked + label:before {
  content: "✓";
  background-color: grey;
  transform: scale(1);
}

:checked + label img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  /* box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333; */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Mi FORM:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" id='myCheckbox1' value="662"  onclick="UpdateCost()"/>
    <label for="myCheckbox1"><img src="Cocina.png" /></label>
  </li>
```

mi JS:

```
function UpdateCost() {
  var sum = 0;
  var gn, elem;
  var gn, elem;
  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    gn = 'myCheckbox'+i;
    elem = document.getElementById(gn);
    if (elem.checked == true) { sum += Number(elem.value); }
  }
  document.getElementById('totalcost').value = sum;
}
```

El error que me salta es: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked')

Comment: hola, es que la imágen es el checkbox... sin las imagenes esta todo funcionando. el problema es cuando enmascaro las checkbox con imagenes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es necesario asignar IDs dinámicos para poder asociar las etiquetas con cada checkbox. Así como lo tienes ahora, es forzoso que existan 10 checkboxes, con id desde `myCheckbox1` hasta `myCheckbox10`, no hay flexibilidad para agregar o quitar.

Para que funcione sin modificar HTML, solo basta una comprobación para verificar que el elemento se pudo obtener correctamente:

```
function UpdateCost() {
  var sum = 0;
  var gn, elem;
  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    gn = 'myCheckbox'+i;
    elem = document.getElementById(gn);
    // ¿Existe el elemento?
    if(elem) {
        // ¿Está marcado?
        if (elem.checked == true) { sum += Number(elem.value); }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('totalcost').value = sum;
}
```

Para tener mayor flexibilidad, te sugiero usar clase en vez de ID y encerrar tanto el checkbox como la imagen dentro del mismo `<label>`; esto permite que cada checkbox cambie al hacer clic en la imagen, además de poder obtenerlos todos con [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) para recorrerlos y analizar su valor.

Tampoco es recomendable poner los eventos directamente en las etiquetas, porque puede complicar la depuración de tus proyectos, lo mejor es hacerlo desde Javascript, teniendo la lógica separada de la presentación:

```js
// Obtener todos los checkbox por clase
let chks = document.querySelectorAll('.chk-sumar');
// Recorrer para asignar evento
chks.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('change', UpdateCost));

function UpdateCost() {
    let sum = 0;

    // Recorrer para sumar
    chks.forEach(elem => {
        if(elem.checked) {
            sum += Number(elem.value);
        }
    });
    // Actualizar costo total
    document.getElementById('totalcost').value = sum;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class='chk-sumar' value="662">
        <img src="Cocina.png"></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class='chk-sumar' value="662">
        <img src="Cocina.png"></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class='chk-sumar' value="662">
        <img src="Cocina.png"></label>
    </li>
</ul>

<input id="totalcost" type="number" value="">
```